# Support of a quasi-coherent sheaf on an affine scheme

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, sheaf-theory

Let $A$ be a commutative ring, $X = \text{Spec }A$, and let $M$ be a $A$-module. The $\mathcal{F} = \tilde M$ is a sheaf on $X$.

Exercise II.5.6 in Hartshorne's *Algebraic Geometry* states that if $A$ is noetherian and $M$ is finitely generated, then $\text{Supp } \mathcal{F} = V(\text{Ann} M)$.

I proved this, but it feels suspicious that I did not use that $A$ should be noetherian. This is my proof:

Let $m_1,\dotsc,m_n$ be generators of $M$. Then $\text{Ann }M = \bigcap _i\text{Ann } m_i$. Also the $m_i$ generate the stalks of $\mathcal{F}$, so $\mathcal{F}_x = 0$ if and only if $(m_i)_x = 0$ for all $i = 1,\dotsc, n$. Hence $\text{Supp }\mathcal{F} = \bigcup_i \text{Supp }m_i = \bigcup_i V(\text{Ann } m_i) = V(\bigcap_i \text{Ann }m_i) = V(\text{Ann }M).$

Did I make any mistake, or can the noetherian hypothesis be omitted here?

Comment: Pretty sure this works. I think the assumption that A is noetherian is relevant for part (c) of the problem (since a coherent sheaf only behaves well on a noetherian scheme).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right, the Noetherian hypothesis is not needed here. Actually, the following is true

*Let $(X, \mathcal{O}_{X})$ be a scheme and $\mathcal{F}$ be a quasi-coherent $\mathcal{O}_{X}$-module of finite type (i.e. a module such that for any point $p \in X$ there exists an open neighbourhood $U$ of $p$ and a surjection $\mathcal{O}_U^n \rightarrow \mathcal{F} \vert_U$), then the underlying topological space of $V(\text{Ann} \mathcal{F})$ is $\text{Supp} \mathcal{F}$.*

As the question is local, the proof is exactly the one you did (you can find it in *Ulrich Görtz, Torsten Wedhorn, Algebraic geometry I*, *Proposition 7.34*).

In my opinion, the reason why the exercise has been put in that way is that if the scheme is noetherian we have the equivalence

$$\textit{quasi-coherent + finite type} \iff \textit{coherent}$$