# About the support of finite type quasicoherent sheaves

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $X$ be a scheme (though I think you can work with ringed space in general) and $\mathscr{F}$ be a finite type quasicoherent sheaf on $X$. Then I want to show that $\mathscr{F}$ has closed support. So here’s what I did. Suppose $X = \operatorname{Spec} A$ is affine and $\mathscr{F} = \widetilde{M}$ with $M$ a finitely generated $A$-module. Then you can show that the support of $\mathscr{F}$ is exactly $V(\operatorname{Ann}(M)) \subseteq \operatorname{Spec} A$ hence is closed (c.f. [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3047650/support-of-a-quasi-coherent-sheaf-on-an-affine-scheme)). But I am not sure about the general case. In particular, write $X$ as a union of affine opens. Then $\mathscr{F}$ will have closed support locally, so the support of $\mathscr{F}$ will be the (possibly infinite) union of the local supports. But I don’t see if there is any reason for this to be closed (as they are closed locally, not closed in $X$ in general, let alone the possibly infinite union).

Extra: according to this argument, if $\mathfrak{p} \in \operatorname{Spec} A \cap \operatorname{Spec} B$ with $\mathscr{F}|_{\operatorname{Spec} A} = \widetilde{M}$ and $\mathscr{F}|_{\operatorname{Spec} B} = \widetilde{N}$, then $M_\mathfrak{p} \neq 0$ will imply that $N_\mathfrak{p} \neq 0$. Is there any way to see this explicitly?

Comment: Remember, if $U_\alpha$ is an open cover a $X$ so that $V \cap U_\alpha$ is closed in $U_\alpha$ for all $\alpha$, then $V$ is closed. This holds for any topological space. To see this, just note that the complement of $V$ is the union of open subsets of $U_\alpha$.

Comment: Ok, now I see how to finish off my proof